# (React Native) How to uploading App Signing Key to Google Play Console?

Tags: android, react-native, store, keystore, playback

im developing an app in react native, but i have some problem in deploying to Play Store. I already generating an upload key using keytool as the react native's documentation said, and i got a file named `<my-upload-key>.keystore`. Im done with editting `build.gradle` and `gradle.properties` to configure my upload key.

My problem is what should i choose with these options, should i choose
**"Let Google create and manage my app signing key (recommended)"** 
OR
**"Export and upload a key and certificate"**??

[image]

Once i choosed the **"Let Google create and manage my app signing key"**, then my app successfuly uploaded and published in playstore, but when i download it from play store, my app wont open and only show white blank screen. My app running well when im using generated APK from react native.

If i choose **Export and upload a key and certificate**, they want the file uploaded as zip file containing the PEM file.

Am i miss a step in uploading the app to Play Console?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i already solve my problems.
The problem is not on my signing key or upload key or generated keystore.
All is fine by choosing letting google to manage our signing key.
But the problem is on the SoLoader in `react-native` `0.61.4`, many people have same issue with me, the issue was the app being force closed when the app uploaded to playstore or shows only white blank screen.

The solution is to add some configuration on `android/app/build.gradle`
Here is the code to add in `build.gradle`

```js
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
        force "com.facebook.soloader:soloader:0.8.0"
    }
}
```

add this code to the file's root, all is done.

Answer (score 1):

Please follow React-native's [official documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android) for signing APK & Publishing to Playstore

Just signing with the method described in Official Documentation and Publish to Playstore with "Let Google create and manage my app signing key". when you succesfully publish you will get new signing certificate and credential so next time you can use this new certificate for signing your APK .

If your App was succesfully published but it is not working or getting crashed there must be an error in your App, are you 100% Sure that it was mistake in publishing not in App?

Comment: yes i already do that, my app successfuly published. But when my app installed on my phone, it only shows white blank screen. Before published on playstore, my app running well on `react-native run-android`

Comment: react-native run-android works on debug mode .

The APK that you uploaded to Playstore is Release Mode please search difference between these modes.

Comment: there must be some problem with your signed APK it has nothing to do with publishing to playstore.  check your release mode APK that you generated after signing with a release key store.

Comment: Hi, i already solve my problem. It was not my keystore, but the problem is the SoLoader on react-native 0.61.4, i must force it to use version 0.8.0 by add some configuration on `android/app/build.gradle`

Answer (score 0):

Just follow below steps:

https://medium.com/@klpdjolanta/13-steps-to-deploying-react-native-android-app-to-google-play-store-using-android-studio-c2ec0c434145

and also try to understand below:
https://medium.com/google-developer-experts/exploring-google-play-app-signing-b4d296f4ee9